# pjax: how to make back button re-request html from the server

Tags: javascript, pjax

The html code that pjax inserts into a pjax container includes some javascript code. It works just fine - when pjax does the insertion, the js is executed.

However, it does not happen when user clicks on browser's "back" button.

Example situation:

- User goes to /aaa
- User clicks on a pjax'ed link to /bbb (the requested
  html contains js, which is executed)
- User clicks on a pjax'ed link to /ccc
- User clicks on a pjax'ed link to /bbb (the requested
  html contains js, which is executed)
- User clicks on a pjax'ed link to /ccc
- User clicks on the back button - the js is not executed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To load the jquery added in your page, you need to call it after the pjax event is completed.

To make it work also on browser's back/ forward button clicks, you can use pjax-end event.

```
$("#pjax_container_id").bind('pjax:end', function() {
  // call your jquery functions
});
```

Hope this would help you.

Thanks.